# Single Server request per page vs SPA Application

Tags: angularjs, httprequest, single-page-application

I had the idea to make a SPA application using angularJS and then just sending AJAX updates to the server when I need.

My initial idea would be make the client application fly, but if I have to do an AJAX round trip to the server, I think the time would be approximately the same as to request a single web page.

Requesting a page just has more bytes of data, is not like I'm requesting 20 resources like in this article: https://community.compuwareapm.com/community/display/PUB/Best+Practices+on+Network+Requests+and+Roundtrips

I would be requesting a page or resource per request.

So in the end even if I create my client side application as a SPA using angularJS, these requests (would have to be synchronous and show a please wait message while they don't return, as I don't want to user to take more actions before I make sure his request passes validation and is processed correctly) would take some time and make user wait, just about the same time as requesting a full page.

I think SPA pages would be very useful if I have like a wizard on my app with multiple pages/steps and at the end, submit the results of wizard, to the server, which I don't.

Also found this article:
https://help.optimizely.com/hc/en-us/articles/203326524-AngularJS-Backbone-js-and-other-Single-Page-Applications

> One of the biggest advantages of Single Page Apps is that they reduce
>   data transfer. As a result, pages after the initial loading usually
>   can be displayed faster and seem more interactive.

But I don't believe this last quote is really true.

Am I right, or is there a way that I'm not seeing to build an application that would look like it's executing locally?

I know how guys will start saying "depends on what you want", but lets focus on this scenario where there's no wizards.

Answer (score 0):

What ever you said is right. But most of the frameworks(Angular,BackBone) you take they are going to cache the templates of html on the browser so the rendering would be pretty fast compared to the normal applications. Traditional apps will have to fetch the html from the server for each request which is a time consuming one.

Hope this helps you!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to go through that syncronous server side validation step for each page request, then there is probably no big advantage to using AngularJS.

If you are requesting a page and then **manipulating that page's contents once it's loaded** you might want to consider AngularJS. A good example would be requesting a page that displays a list of items. Now let's say we want to search that list or order it in different ways. Rather than using AJAX to call the server to filter the list and then re-render it, it could be much faster to user AngularJS to filter and re-render the list without making any further requests to the server.